# dependency on column EF6

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

I get an error when I try to do a migration

> The object 'DF_dbo.dbMetrics_metricName' is dependent on column 'metricName'.
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN metricName failed because one or more objects access this column.

I am trying to change it from a GUID to a string as I want to be able to manually add my ID's in.

```
 public override void Up()
    {
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.dbMetrics");
        AlterColumn("dbo.dbMetrics", "metricName", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.dbMetrics", "metricName");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.dbMetrics");
        AlterColumn("dbo.dbMetrics", "metricName", c => c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.dbMetrics", "metricName");
    }
```

Here is my migration class file

Comment: is `DF_dbo.dbMetrics_metricName` the name of your primary key? If so, you can try using the overload of `DropPrimaryKey` that takes `string, string` as table name and object name.